# IIF IsNothing expression example

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssrs-expression

I'm using `SSRS 2008` and am trying to create an `expression` where if date field A is greater than date field B or date field A is NULL then this filter will select this record.  How do I do this?

I tried this expression to select `NULL` date fields, but it is not working.  I set the datatype to "Text" for now--should I set this to boolean instead?  If so, then how can I modify this expression?

```
=iif(isnothing(Fields!A_date.Value),"yes","no")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
=IIF((CDATE(Fields!A_date.Value)>CDate(Fields!B_date.Value)) OR ISNothing(Fields!A_date.Value),"Yes","NO")
```

Try this !!!