# SSRS Field not Displaying as Expected

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a stored procedure that provides data like the following:

```
 CREATE TABLE Table1
     ([period] int, [state] varchar(2), [company] varchar(8), [rate] numeric, [rate_num] numeric, [rate_denom] numeric)
     ;
 /*
 -- Alternate option
    
 CREATE TABLE Table1
     ([period] int, [state] varchar(2), [company] varchar(8), [rate] DECIMAL(7,6), [rate_num] DECIMAL(7,2), [rate_denom] DECIMAL(10,2))
 ;
 */
    
INSERT INTO Table1
    ([period], [state], [company], [rate], [rate_num], [rate_denom])
VALUES
    (202004, 'ST', 'Company1', 0.000497, NULL, 10562.51),
    (202004, 'ST', 'Company1', 0.000497, 50, 6984.57),
    (202004, 'ST', 'Company1', 0.000497, 100, 223199.73),
    (202004, 'ST', 'Company1', 0.000497, NULL, 60627.17),
    (202005, 'ST', 'Company1', NULL, NULL, 4291.98),
    (202005, 'ST', 'Company1', NULL, NULL, 420617.49),
    (202005, 'ST', 'Company1', NULL, NULL, 49403.02),
    (202005, 'ST', 'Company1', NULL, NULL, 64282.61),
    (202005, 'ST', 'Company2', NULL, NULL, 2287.94),
    (202005, 'ST', 'Company2', NULL, NULL, 63990.73),
    (202005, 'ST', 'Company2', NULL, NULL, 455426.94),
    (202006, 'ST', 'Company2', 0, NULL, 3000.9),
    (202006, 'ST', 'Company2', 0, NULL, 2000.61),
    (202006, 'ST', 'Company2', 0, 0, 60000),
    (202007, 'ST', 'Company2', 0.000131, NULL, 11434.4),
    (202007, 'ST', 'Company2', 0.000131, NULL, 2347.94),
    (202007, 'ST', 'Company2', 0.000131, 97.5, 727027.39)
;
```

```
+--------+-------+----------+----------+----------+------------+
| period | state | company  |   rate   | rate_num | rate_denom |
+--------+-------+----------+----------+----------+------------+
| 202004 | ST    | Company1 | 0.000497 | NULL     |   10562.51 |
| 202004 | ST    | Company1 | 0.000497 | 50       |    6984.57 |
| 202004 | ST    | Company1 | 0.000497 | 100      |  223199.73 |
| 202004 | ST    | Company1 | 0.000497 | NULL     |   60627.17 |
| 202005 | ST    | Company1 | NULL     | NULL     |    4291.98 |
| 202005 | ST    | Company1 | NULL     | NULL     |  420617.49 |
| 202005 | ST    | Company1 | NULL     | NULL     |   49403.02 |
| 202005 | ST    | Company1 | NULL     | NULL     |   64282.61 |
| 202005 | ST    | Company2 | NULL     | NULL     |    2287.94 |
| 202005 | ST    | Company2 | NULL     | NULL     |   63990.73 |
| 202005 | ST    | Company2 | NULL     | NULL     |  455426.94 |
| 202006 | ST    | Company2 | 0        | NULL     |     3000.9 |
| 202006 | ST    | Company2 | 0        | NULL     |    2000.61 |
| 202006 | ST    | Company2 | 0        | 0        |      60000 |
| 202007 | ST    | Company2 | 0.000131 | NULL     |    11434.4 |
| 202007 | ST    | Company2 | 0.000131 | NULL     |    2347.94 |
| 202007 | ST    | Company2 | 0.000131 | 97.5     |  727027.39 |
+--------+-------+----------+----------+----------+------------+
```

My problem occurs when I try and use `rate` in my SSRS matrix versus calculating rate based on `rate_num / rate_denom`. I am using The following code for `rate` and `rate_calc`. `rate` and `rate_calc` represent the same data. `rate` was calculated in SQL vs `rate_calc` being an expression created in SSRS to calculate `rate`.

```
-- Rate_calc
=IIF(Sum(Fields!rate_denom.Value) <= 0, "", Sum(Fields!rate_num.Value) / Sum(Fields!rate_denom.Value))

-- Rate
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!rate.Value), "", Fields!rate.Value)
```

My SSRS table and group structure is similar to the below table.
[image: ssrs_image_update]

I get the output below which also contains my expected output. When using `rate` it seems to bypass the grouping and fill the rows which are specific to each individual company. For example 202004 only had data for Company1 but the same info shows for Company2. Neither company had data in 202005 and only Company2 had data in the remaining periods.

```
-- Output

+----------+-------+-----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| Company  | State |           | 202007 | 202006 | 202005 | 202004 |
+----------+-------+-----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| Company1 | ST    | Rate_Calc |        |        | 0.00%  | 0.05%  |
|          |       | Rate      | 0.01%  | 0.00%  |        | 0.05%  |
| Company2 | ST    | Rate_Calc | 0.01%  | 0.00%  | 0.00%  |        |
|          |       | Rate      | 0.01%  | 0.00%  |        | 0.05%  |
+----------+-------+-----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+


-- Expected

+----------+-------+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| Company  | State |          | 202007 | 202006 | 202005 | 202004 |
+----------+-------+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| Company1 | ST    | Expected |        |        |        | 0.05%  |
| Company2 | ST    | Expected | 0.01%  | 0.00%  |        |        |
+----------+-------+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Am I using the `rate` field wrong? Otherwise I could try and use `IsNothing` but sometimes I need to `SUM` values for a period which may also contain a null value. Any suggestions on achieving the expected output are appreciated.

Comment: Maybe it will be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917670/iif-isnothing-expression-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, I built the exact same matrix from scratch and it worked. I was not able to pinpoint the problem and made no changes to the data.